# Having trouble with php and sql LIMIT

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

Does anyone see anything wrong with this, I am getting no data on my tables.

```
$a=1;
$b= 10;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM playlists LIMIT :start, :results';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindParam(':start', $a, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindParam(':results',$b, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$playlists = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
```

Short version of my table

```
   <?php foreach ($playlists as $p) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
    <?php echo $p['playlistName']; ?>              
                            </td>
                        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Correct me if im wrong but this should return a max of 10 results starting at 1.

Comment: How to use LIMIT https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php

Comment: Sure you can bind limit, @Charlotte - but columns or tables, no.

Comment: Might I ask where you have hidden the `->execute();`

Comment: Thanks for the links, this is all still very new to me I have been trying to get this working for the past few hours

Comment: The code will work if you EXECUTE the PREPARED statement `$statement->execute()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: OMG thankyou im and idiot